# Error while parsing json using gson on android

Tags: android, gson

I was following this tutorial for gson-android

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

My json is

```
{"IsAuthenticated":true,"BusinessId":57,"Success":true,"ErrorId":0}
```

I have created my model object:

LoginResponse.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.xxxx.xxxx.R.string;

public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("Sucess")
    private Boolean sucess;

    @SerializedName("IsAuthenticated")
    private Boolean isAuthenticated;

    @SerializedName("BusinessId")
    private String businessId;

    @SerializedName("ErrorId")
    private string errorId;

    public Boolean getSucess() {
        return sucess;
    }

    public void setSucess(Boolean sucess) {
        this.sucess = sucess;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAuthenticated() {
        return isAuthenticated;
    }

    public void setIsAuthenticated(Boolean isAuthenticated) {
        this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }

    public String getBusinessId() {
        return businessId;
    }

    public void setBusinessId(String businessId) {
        this.businessId = businessId;
    }

    public string getErrorId() {
        return errorId;
    }

    public void setErrorId(string errorId) {
        this.errorId = errorId;
    }

}
```

My app is getting force close after running this code.

LOGCAT

```
    07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 67
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.example.xxxx.loginActivity.ValidateUser(LoginActivity.java:300)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.example.xxxx.loginActivity.access$0(LoginActivity.java:276)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.example.xxxx.loginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:222)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.example.xxxx.loginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     ... 4 more
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 67
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
07-04 12:22:40.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2694):     ... 14 more
```

.. and this is how i did that

```
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        LoginResponse myResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, LoginResponse.class);
        Log.d(TAG, myResponse.getBusinessId().toString());



    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to download file");
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? I just followed the things in the tut. Could anyone help me.

**UPDATE:**

after correcting string to String and other things, I was able to fix the app crash. Still I am unable to get the object.

the updated log here

```
07-08 05:02:53.625: W/System.err(869): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at com.example.xxxx.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:238)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at com.example.xxxx.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-08 05:02:53.656: W/System.err(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-08 05:02:53.675: W/System.err(869):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dead googled this , but didn't get a solution

Comment: try this,  hold the json values in string type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving from Gson is telling you that it's expecting to find a `{` at the 67th column (character) in your JSON. This means `errorId` is an object type in your Java class, not a number (e.g. `int`, `long`) or a `String` (see last paragraph below regarding automatic `String` conversions).

Looking at your code, you have ...

```
@SerializedName("ErrorId")
private string errorId;
```

Apparently you have created a `string` class (lowercase `s`), have used it, and Gson is trying to deserialize to it. This is why you should *never* do that. First, classes is Java should start with an uppercase letter. Second you should never create classes with the same names as system ones. (Option B would be that the Java class you show *isn't* what is actually running and there's some other object type there).

If you fix that by changing it to a `String` the error will go away. Even though `errorId` (and `businessId`) is now a `String` in your Java, Gson will actually automatically convert number types in JSON to a `String` type in a Java class. You also need to fix the spelling error in `sucess` or it will end up being `null` because that doesn't exist in the JSON and Gson silently ignores any missing elements.

Answer (score 1):

your

```
   @SerializedName("BusinessId")
    private String businessId;

    @SerializedName("ErrorId")
    private string errorId;
```

**should be Integers**

```
  @SerializedName("BusinessId")
    private int businessId;

    @SerializedName("ErrorId")
    private int errorId;
```

Comment: Gson doesn't care. It will convert numbers to String automatically. That's not what that error means.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your LoginResponse.java:

```
@SerializedName("Sucess")
```

should be

```
@SerializedName("Success")
```

Maybe there're more problems though, could you check that the JSON you're trying to parse is indeed what you expect it to be?

Comment: The variable sucess should be renamed to success too.

Comment: The variable name shouldn't matter if it's annotated, right? Of course, its always good to keep your spelling correct :)

Comment: Absolutely- and of course if you misname the json key behaviour should be that it just doesn't get set!

Comment: now its org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ( please find the log in the updated question )

Answer (score 0):

Is `private string errorId;` really lower case there? You might want `String`, or `int` (both will work).

Reflectiony stuff in gson reads your field type and thinks it must be an object that a nested json object can be mapped to. Could explain `Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 67`: your reflectiony mapper is expecting an object (but not `java.lang.String`) type for `ErrorId` because you've given it something it thinks is another kind of object- mysterious `string`. `String`, however, is a class it knows how to deal with.